# changed my mysql root password and now I cant log in

Tags: mysql, passwords, xampp, admin

This may sound dumb. I was having a problem with mysql so I logged into the mysql admin panel from the xampp control panel. I noticed that 'root' did not have a password so I changed it to include a simple password. It is on my localhost but I thought this was a good thing to do anyway.

Here is the problem.... Now when I attempt to access the mysql admin page from the xampp control panel, I am prevented because the control panel does not supply a password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have root access to the server? What OS is the server running on?

Comment: using xampp on Win7. I restarted it a few times and now it appears to be working properly.

Mysteries of life...